# Will the multi-touch trackpad on my Windows PC still work when i install Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, hardware, trackpad, gestures

I'm going to install Ubuntu as a dual-boot option on my Windows 8 pc. My pc trackpad has multi-touch capability (two-time scroll, etc) and I was wondering, will I still have those multi-touch capabilities when using Ubuntu?

If not, will there likely be any gestures at all besides simple tapping? At least something for scrolling??

I don't know the software brand of my my trackpad and k can't look out up at the moment.

Any help us greatly appreciated!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know two finger scrolling should work. It worked on my old Dell just fine on 12.04, and I see no reason for Canonical to get rid of that so it should still be there. Other gestures might be automatically available or its easy enough to install packages like that.